# How to join two tables in oracle sqldeveloper to get single line result

Tags: oracle

I have the below table structure

`Table1`

| Id | StationDepartureId | StationArrivalID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 8 | 10001 | 10002 |

and the second table `stationTable`

| Id | StationId | ActualID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10001 | 11111 |
| 2 | 10002 | 22222 |

Here the `stationDepartureID`, `StationArrivalID` is same as the second table `stationTables` `StationID`. I want to get the result

Id, StationDepartureids actualID and StationArrivalIDs ActualID as the result.

i.e.

| Id | ActualDepartureId | ActualArrivalId |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 8 | 11111 | 22222 |

What I tried is a left join on both tables based on 2 columns but this results in 2 rows. Can I get some help on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Join to the same table twice and in the first join condition match on the departure station and in the second join condition match on the arrival station:

```sql
SELECT t.id,
       d.actualid AS actualdepartureid,
       a.actualid AS actualarrivalid
FROM   table1 t
       INNER JOIN stationTable d
       ON t.stationdepartureid = d.stationid
       INNER JOIN stationTable a
       ON t.stationarrivalid = a.stationid
```

*(Note: you can change `INNER JOIN` to `LEFT OUTER JOIN` is that meets your requirements.)*

or you can use correlated sub-queries:

```sql
SELECT t.id,
       (SELECT d.actualid FROM stationTable d WHERE t.stationdepartureid = d.stationid)
         AS actualdepartureid,
       (SELECT a.actualid FROM stationTable a WHERE t.stationarrivalid = a.stationid)
         AS actualarrivalid
FROM   table1 t
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE Table1 (Id, StationDepartureId, StationArrivalID) AS
SELECT 8, 10001, 10002 FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE stationTable (Id, StationId, ActualID) AS
SELECT 1, 10001, 11111 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 10002, 22222 FROM DUAL;
```

Both output:

| ID | ACTUALDEPARTUREID | ACTUALARRIVALID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 8 | 11111 | 22222 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/T_2QJtaE)